# Difficulty understanding java code in android

Tags: java, android

What is the meaning of `(EditText)` in the following snippet ?

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

I understand that it is the declaration of a new instance of class EditText...

But i'm puzzled with the `(EditText)` part ?  What does it mean ?

Comment: it is a class cast. revise your Java concepts before going ahead with Android it will make things easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `findViewById` method returns a `View` object and to make it an EditText object that it represents you have to cast it that way. You actually want to work with instance of `EditText` and not `View` so that you can have access to specific properties of `EditText`

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

The above code won't be valid as `EditText` and `View` are not the same, so it need to be cast/converted.

Answer (score 2):

It is an explicit class cast: the generic View object returned by `findViewById()` is cast / converted to an EditText object.

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Answer (score 2):

`EditText` is an android class that represents an edit field on the Ui of your application. In the current case it looks as if you have defined an edittext field in the xml of your activity and you are now getting a reference to it so that you can interact with it programatically using the methods on the class.

You can see everything you can do with it: [Android Developer: EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

If you did not cast it to an `EditText` you would only be able to handle it as a View [Android Developer: View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html%20with%20it.)